# Video not visible on mobile devices

Tags: video, flowplayer

i am working on a website that contains videos. It is mainly a mobile site. I am using flowplayer to play the videos. The videos are playing well in non-mobile devices. I tested with some android devices the video is not visible but could hear the audio play in the background. Any solution? thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
<div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
<a id="switch" class="btn btn-danger" data-quality="high">Play HQ</a>
<div id="flow" class="flowplayer aside-time play-button center is-splash" data-ratio="0.5625" data-volume="0.5" style="background:black;width: 100%;margin-top:2em;">

<video >
  <source id="palyer" src="<?php echo $result->location?>"></source>
    Your Browser Is Not Supported     
</video>
</div>
```

I followed this [blog](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html). Video format used is mp4.

Comment: you gotta give more information... what kind of video... where did you encode it, etc...

Comment: i have updated my answer with more info. @WagnerPatriota